# How to change timer format

Tags: java, format, timer

Ive created timer. How can I change the timer format to ***second*** so that it wont be long number? Thanks

```
private long startTime  = System.currentTimeMillis();
Timer timer  = new Timer(1000, this);
timer.start();

timer.stop();
long endTime    = System.currentTimeMillis();
long timeInMilliseconds = (endTime - startTime);
```

Comment: Which of the three JDK "Timer" clasees are you using?  Or is this a Timer class from a 3rd party library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a constant SECOND and use it like this:

```
new Timer(1 * SECOND, this);
```

Answer (score 6):

divide by 1000 for seconds from milliseconds.

Comment: How could I reset the time when I click a button? I tried to use timer.reset() but it doesnt work..Thanks

Comment: As Eddie mentioned, it may depend on which implementation of Timer you are using.  If .reset() doesn't behave as you expect it, you can always just throw out the current timer and instantiate a new one.